# if statment using macro in cmake

Tags: cmake

I have a CMAKE file and I'm defining a macro and I want to use this macro as a condition?

I have this example cmake file - and I'm defining `LIT_INDECATOR` as 1 or 0 and want to use its value in an IF statement for finding LIB

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)
project(test)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
add_definitions(-DLIT_INDECATOR=1)


set(TEST_PRIFIX ../lib/internal/libtest)


if(LIT_INDECATOR EQUALS 1) # <-- how to make this line works?
 find_library(SOME_LIB
            NAMES libtest
            HINTS "${TEST_PRIFIX}"
            )
    if(NOT SOME_LIB)
        message(FATAL_ERROR "SOME_LIB library not found")
    else()
        message("SOME_LIB library found")
    endif()
endif()


link_directories(${TEST_PRIFIX})

SET(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(test ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_link_libraries(test libtest)
```

Comment: Try if(LIT_INDECATOR)

Comment: @msteel9999 not working

Comment: `add_definitions` adds macro for **compiler**. `if()` command checks **CMake** variable. A compiler macro and a CMake variable are absolutely **unrelated** things, even they have the same name.

Comment: A general approach: define CMake variable first. Using this variable in `if` command, you may *conditionally* add a compiler macro and add other libraries.

Comment: @Tsyvarev thank you it works, write it as an answer and i will accept it